# ¿Como hacer para traer un numero limitado de elementos de un json, y al azar?

Tags: php, array, json, foreach, filtro

como estan?
Estoy haciendo un trabajo para la carrera hecho con php. Lo que necesitaria es hacer que de un json de muchos productos, yo tome solo 4 productos al azar. Mi idea es hacer como que son los 4 productos mas vendidos (por eso un supuesto al azar). Creo que deberia usar un foreach, pero no se  como mas hacerlo para que se me filtren esos 4 elementos al azar.

Tengo lo siguente como JSON:

```
[
 {
     "producto_id": 1,
     "nombre": "Guitarra Acústica Bamboo Diseño",
     "precio": "10.900",
     "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Tamaño 41 </br>⚫ Tapa: Pino </br>⚫ Aro y Fondo: Sapele </br>⚫ Mástil: Okoume </br>⚫ Diapason: Nogal </br>⚫ Puente: Nogal </br>⚫ Terminación: Mate </br>⚫ Clavijas: Blindadas </br>⚫ Trastes: Alpaca </br>⚫ Incluye funda",
     "imagen": "guitarra-acustica2.jpg",
     "imagen_descripcion": "Guitara Acústica de Bamboo con Diseño"
 },
 {
    "producto_id": 2,
    "nombre": "Guitarra Eléctrica Stratocaster 22 Trastes",
    "precio": "18.600",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Formato de guitarra simil Stratocaster </br>⚫ Cuerpo: Madera maciza </br>⚫ Mástil: Arce </br>⚫ Diapasón: MDF Alta densidad </br>⚫ Clavijas de fundición cromadas </br>⚫ Cuerdas de metal </br>⚫ 3 micrófonos: 2 bobina simple, 1 humbucker </br>⚫ 3 perillas: 1 de volumen, 2 de Tono </br>⚫ Selectora de 5 posiciones </br>⚫ 22 trastes </br>⚫ Puente móvil simple estilo Stratocaster </br>⚫ Salida: Jack plug 6.5mm",
    "imagen": "guitarra-electrica2.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Guitarra Eléctrica Stratocaster 22 Trastes"
},
{
    "producto_id": 3,
    "nombre": "Arturia Keylab Essential 49 Teclado Midi Usb Controlador Vst",
    "precio": "38.500",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ 49 teclas con velocidad </br>⚫ Controles: 1 Encoder, 9 Knobs (Potenciometros), 9 faders de 30mm, 6 mutadores de transporte, 4 interruptores de mando, 1 rueda de MODULACIÓN, 1 rueda de PITCH, 8 PADs sensibles a la velocidad. </br>⚫ Conectividad: Salida MIDI, USB, Pedal de sustain. </br>⚫ Funciona como un controlador MIDI universal. </br>⚫ Pantalla LCD de dos líneas. </br>⚫ Compatibilidad de control MCU / HUI. </br>⚫ Modo de reproducción de acordes.",
    "imagen": "teclado-controlador.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Arturia Keylab Essential 49 Teclado Midi Usb Controlador Vst"
},
{
    "producto_id": 4,
    "nombre": "Conn Selmer As501 Saxofón Alto En Mib C/estuche Saxo",
    "precio": "157.000",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Sistema de orificio de cuerpo y tono acústicamente mejorado </br>⚫ Cuerpo y llaves de latón. </br>⚫ Acabado laqueado oro. </br>⚫ Cuello acústico </br>⚫ Apertura automática de G # </br>⚫ Alto F # -key </br>⚫ C # / Bb- tecla de mesa conectada </br>⚫ Gancho de pulgar de metal ajustable </br>⚫ Almohadillas PISONI </br>⚫ Boquilla USA con ligadura y tapa. </br>⚫ Estuche ligero con montaje de mochila",
    "imagen": "saxofon2.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Conn Selmer As501 Saxofón Alto En Mib"
},
{
    "producto_id": 5,
    "nombre": "Batería Pearl Roadshow 4 Cuerpos Bombo 18",
    "precio": "86.200",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Bombo: 18x12. </br>⚫ Redoblante: 13x5. </br>⚫ Tom 1: 10x7. </br>⚫ Tom de piso: 14x10. </br>⚫ Madera: 9 capas de álamo. </br>⚫ Set de platillos: </br>⚫ Hi-Hat 14. </br>⚫ Crash 16. </br>⚫ Ride 20.",
    "imagen": "bateria2.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Batería Pearl Roadshow 4 Cuerpos Bombo 18"
},
{
    "producto_id": 6,
    "nombre": "Par Monitores De Estudio Krk Rp-5 Rokit G3 Negros Near Field",
    "precio": "79.800",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Woofer de 5\u201d de compuesto de vidrio de Aramida </br>⚫ Tweeter de cúpula blanda de 1\u201d </br>⚫ Amplificador de 50W de Clase A-B </br>⚫ 30W LF ⚫ 20W HF </br>⚫ Respuesta en frecuencia: 45Hz - 35kHz </br>⚫ Conectores de entrada: RCA, XLR y TRS de 1/4\u201d </br>⚫ Función de Standby automático </br>⚫ Dimensiones: 284 x 188 x 246mm (alto x ancho x profundo) </br>⚫ Peso: 5,9kg </br>⚫ Color: Negro",
    "imagen": "monitores-de-estudio2.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Par Monitores De Estudio Krk Rp-5 Rokit G3 Negros Near Field"
},
{
    "producto_id": 7,
    "nombre": "Interface De Audio Focusrite Scarlett Solo 3ra Gen",
    "precio": "24.500",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Cantidad de entradas: 2 </br>⚫ Cantidad de salidas: 2 </br>⚫ Tasa de muestreo: 192 kHz </br>⚫ Resolución de audio: 24 bit </br>⚫ Con alimentación fantasma: Sí </br>⚫ Tipos de alimentación: USB </br>⚫ Tipos de conexiones: 1 XLR, 1 phone TRS 6.3 mm, 1 line TRS-TS L/R 6.3 mm out, 1 USB-C 2.0 </br>⚫ Software compatible: Live lite, Pro tools first, Garageband, Auria pro, FL studio </br>⚫ Altura: 43.5 mm </br>⚫ Ancho: 143.5 mm </br>⚫ Profundidad: 95.8 mm </br>⚫ Peso: 320 g",
    "imagen": "interfaz-audio.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Interface De Audio Focusrite Scarlett Solo 3ra Gen"
},
{
    "producto_id": 8,
    "nombre": "Auriculares Beyerdynamic DT880 Pro 250 Ohm",
    "precio": "57.600",
    "caracteristicas": "Características: </br></br>⚫ Dinámicos </br> Semi abiertos </br>⚫ Respuesta en frecuencia: 5-35.000 Hz </br>⚫ Impedancia: 250 Ohm </br>⚫ Sensibilidad: 96dB </br>⚫ Incluye cable en espiral de 3m </br>⚫ Peso con cable: 390 g </br>⚫ Peso sin cable 307 g </br> Conector minijak de 3,5mm </br>⚫ Incluye adaptador a Jack de 6,3mm y bolsa",
    "imagen": "auriculares.jpg",
    "imagen_descripcion": "Auriculares Beyerdynamic DT880 Pro 250 Ohm"
}
```

]

Y los imprimo de la siguiente manera:

```
    <?php
    foreach($productos as $producto):
    ?>
    
        <a href="index.php?s=productos-detalle&id=<?= $producto->getProductoId();?>" class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <article>  
                <img src="imagenes/productos/<?= $producto->getImagen();?>" alt="<?= $producto->getImagenDescripcion();?>">
                <div>
                    <h2><?= $producto->getNombre()?></h2>
                    <p>$ <?= $producto->getPrecio();?></p>
                </div>                
            </article>
        </a>           

    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

Pero quisiera saber entonces como filtro solo 4 al azar de esos 8 elementos.

Saludos, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te sugiero crear un arreglo numérico con la cantidad de productos, por ejemplo, tienes 8 productos en ese arreglo, entonces:

```
$seleccionar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

Desordena con [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.shuffle.php) y ya solo necesitas un ciclo para mostrar la cantidad deseada:

```
<?php
// Mostrar cuatro productos
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    // Tomar índice del arreglo desordenado
    $index = $seleccionar[$i];
    // Seleccionar el producto por índice
    $producto = $productos[$index];
?>

    <a href="index.php?s=productos-detalle&id=<?= $producto->getProductoId();?>" class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <article>  
            <img src="imagenes/productos/<?= $producto->getImagen();?>" alt="<?= $producto->getImagenDescripcion();?>">
            <div>
                <h2><?= $producto->getNombre()?></h2>
                <p>$ <?= $producto->getPrecio();?></p>
            </div>                
        </article>
    </a>           

<?php
}
?>
```

El uso de un arreglo adicional es para evitar modificar el original, porque podrías necesitarlo para realizar otras tareas.

Comment: Gracias! No conocía el shuffle. Termine usando eso mas un array_splice($productos, 4) para filtrar solo los primeros 4 elementos luego de haber hecho la mezcla.